# Keep track of visited patches in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

How do i keep track of visited patches. A turtle is moving every where and i need to keep track of it that which patch is visited by a turtle or which is un-visited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do this and their utility depends on your needs.  Here is one way, using a list for memory.
    turtles-own [memory]

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 1 [set memory (list patch-here)]
end

to move  ;;turtle proc
  let unvisited patches with [not member? self [memory] of myself]
  move-to one-of unvisited
  set memory lput patch-here memory
end
```

In this simple example, the memory list grows without bound. In a real application, you probably will want to remove old memories after a certain length.

Comment: It creates a list, but how can i query that list if this location is present in that list

Comment: Did you look at the creation of `unvisited` in the `move` proc?  I think that answers your question.  If not, please rephrase.